# Get current axis width of Bokeh figure

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I need to know the current width of a Bokeh axis (which might have changed size since creation through use of the `resize` tool) when using Bokeh server.

`figure.plot_width` only prints the overall width of the figure, including the tick labels, axis labels and margins, not the width of the axis area. Also, it doesn't seem to get updated when the figure is resized.

How do I get the current axis width in a Bokeh server?

---

Minimal example, display with `bokeh serve plot_width.py`:

```
# file name: plot_width.py

import bokeh.plotting
import numpy

def print_current_plot_width():
    print "Current plot width: ", p.plot_width

x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x + numpy.random.random(100)

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=[0, 10], tools='resize')
l = p.line(x, y)

print "Initial plot width: ", p.plot_width

bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_periodic_callback(print_current_plot_width , 1000)

bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Comment: As of Bokeh `0.11` this information is not transmitted outside the client. There are some upcoming features that might provide a workaround (user defined namespaces + JS callbacks), and perhaps it could also potentially make sense to expose it directly in some way, but that would require new development. Can you make a GitHub issue on the project issue tracker (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss this with the core dev team?

Comment: @bigreddot: [Done](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3747)